# SSIS How to run the same stored procedure with different parameters each time

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a simple SP that has 2 parameters to execute. The output will go into an excel file. Thru SSIS I want to accomplish the following:
Run the SP with first set of parameters and place output into excel.
Run the same SP with a different set of parameters and place output in the same excel but In a different tab. Same process 12 times placing results into 12 different tabs in the same excel file. I'm fairly new to SSIS and the way I though of doing this was to have 12 different execute sql tasks outputting into 12 different excel files. Please if there is a more efficient way of achieving it would be great help! Thanks

Comment: It's not easy, but you can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634418/how-to-create-dynamic-excel-sheets-based-on-table-data).

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic487837-19-1.aspx may help.